# Loading geoJSON to Cesium does not work but I get no errors

Tags: gis, postgis, geojson, cesiumjs

I try to pass data from PostGIS to Cesium, I believe the simpler way is to use GeoJSON.

To test it I do a query to my PostGIS to get some geoJSON data

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(mygeom) 
FROM mytable where id = 370;
```

then I copy the result to a cesium sandcastle to see how it works

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');

const greenPolygon = viewer.entities.add({
  name: "Green extruded polygon",
  polygon: {
    hierarchy : Cesium.GeoJsonDataSource.load({"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[386788.842267334,4204512.29371444],[386804.47751787,4204512.29371444],[386804.47751787,4204510.66293459],[386788.854170836,4204510.66293459],[386788.842267334,4204512.29371444]]]]}),
    extrudedHeight: 100000.0,
    material: Cesium.Color.YELLOW.withAlpha(0.5),
    outline : true,
    outlineColor : Cesium.Color.BLACK,
    closeTop: true,
    closeBottom: true
  },
});


viewer.zoomTo(viewer.entities);
```

I get no errors in the cesium sandcastle console, but I also see no polygon on the map. The geometry in my PostGIS table is `geometry(MultiPolygon,2100)`, I dont know if this is the issue.

Please advice

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

CesiumJS will not understand your coordinates(ex 386788.842267334,4204512.29371444) defined in your custom spatial reference system.
You must specify coordinates using geographic latitude, and longitude.

Comment: But those where supposed to be coords selected from PostGIS in a GeoJSON. Anyway, if this is not the case, what can I do ? How can I convert coords to lon/lat ? Thanks